# jQuery multiple dropdown class filter with error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have 2 dropdowns, one for country and one for business type. If the user chooses Australia, then all business types found in Australia would be displayed. The content for each business is shown in a div with class names pertaining to the country and business type, as well as 'all'.

I have used a script that I found on stack overflow & other forums, apologies to the person who wrote it - I can't find it right now... I have the functionality for displaying the correct filtered content, but not for showing an error or no-results message.

Ignore the conditional code I have now - I'm not very good with jQuery - I rarely code these days, but I'm trying to show no-results when both dropdown values are not found. Here is the sample code with a jsfiddle link:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0pg2k17/7/)

```js
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).join(".");
  $("div#group").find("div.block").hide();
  if ($("div#group").find("div.block").hide()) {
    $("div#group").find("div.block." + filters).show();

  } else {
    $("div#group").find("div.noresults").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#filter {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0a7fb3;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#filter span,
#filter form,
#filter fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

#filter fieldset {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.all {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> View by:</span>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select id="location" class="filterby">
     <option value="all">Show All</option>
     <option value="australia">Australia</option>
     <option value="singapore">Singapore</option>
     <option value="newzealand">New Zealand</option>
     <option value="usa">USA</option>
     <option value="uk">UK</option>
     <option value="vietnam">Vietnam</option>
     <option value="global">Global</option>
     <option value="othercountry">Other</option>
  </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type" class="filterby">
     <option value="all">Show All Types</option>
     <option value="accommodation">Accommodation</option>
     <option value="app">App/Technology</option>
     <option value="business">Business</option>
     <option value="health">Health</option>
     <option value="hospitality">Hospitality</option>
     <option value="education">Education</option>
     <option value="retail">Retail</option>
     <option value="services">Services</option>
     <option value="travel">Travel</option>
  </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="group">
  <div class="block noresults">
    <p>no results</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>1 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all vietnam  travel">
    <p>2 all vietnam travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>3 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all australia accommodation travel">
    <p>4 all australia accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all australia">
    <p>5 all australia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block all vietnam accommodation">
    <p>6 all vietnam accommodation</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/Lpmosk2g/

Comment: Also you could do this by determining if any blocks are visible after the query https://jsfiddle.net/678n1qsf/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen this is exactly what I want, thanks so much - & also obvious now that I see it :)

Comment: @Landy also great, thanks!